# Genetic mutations in plants

Tags: botany, plant-physiology, mutations

I am trying to plant some trees which are usually native to colder climates into Subtropical climate, is there any possibility that if i plant these 20 trees saplings in winters they will grow to be a tree, due to some random genetic mutation, given all nutrients all provided to it?

Tree in Question is [Deodar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cedrus_deodara)

Comment: Mutations occur more-or-less at random and are only rarely beneficial, but the trivial answer to "any chance" is yes. ———  To improve your question I suggest you think about what you really want to know. If you are interested in whether you can get that species to grow where you live ask that on [Gardening.SE]. If you want to know about genetic adaptation in trees, then you could try to reformulate your question for this site. However, I think you would benefit from reading some introductory material on [evolution](https://evolution.berkeley.edu/evolibrary/article/evo_01) first.

Comment: I have found that when learning about a new area starting with a relatively accessible and reliable source like [Khan Academy](http://khanacademy.org/science/biology/) is very helpful. Wikipedia is also generally a good starting point and you can then check their references. Online platforms called MOOCs offer free (or very low cost) courses on a wide variety of subjects — two I am familiar with are [Coursera](http://coursera.org) and [edX](http://edx.org). Finally, textbooks with a good level of detail are also freely available online e.g. from [NCBI](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/).

Answer (score 1):

I think that the potential survival of your seedlings could more likely be credited to your care and management than random genetic mutations. While, of course, DNA mutations [happen during cell replication](http://www.uwyo.edu/bio1000skh/lecture35.htm), evolution at the whole-plant scale primarily occurs over the course of generations, not the lifespan of a single plant. You may well be able to get these trees to thrive in your environment with some care and love, although they may not grow as vigorously. Here is [a link](https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/ornamental/trees/cedar/growing-cedar-trees.htm) to a gardening website with tips on growing ceaders in a home garden, although I agree with the commenter that you'll get much better help at the Gardening and Landscaping Exchange!

Best of luck with your horticultural endeavors!